# store path in variables and use in windows dos command line

Tags: windows, command-line

in batch file, i can use

```
set srcpath=%cd%
```

to store the current folder's path in variable `srcpath` then use it later.

But suppose i'm in the dos command already, seems that does not work.

is there a way to in windows command line, store path in a variable then use it later ?

Comment: `seems that does not work` what does that mean? it should work as expected. If it doesn't you shold provide more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows 7 to set a variable equal to current directory:

```
C:\Program Files>set p=%cd%
```

**Test:**

```
C:\Program Files>echo %p%
C:\Program Files

C:\Program Files>cd \

C:\>echo %p%
C:\Program Files
```

Comment: the code is just the same as what the OP posted

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc No it's not. Please read it again.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't see how `set srcpath=%cd%` and `set p=%cd%` are different apart from the variable names?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc He shows how to use it correctly. As the answer has been accepted that was presumably what the OP was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I always start my scripts with a var to keep track of the current directory so I can run scripts anywhere
`set CURDIR=%~dp0`
`set srcpath=%~dp0`

When calling on it, you need to know that it includes the \ in the path so exclude it when calling on sub directories and always use quotes.

`Start "title" "%srcpath%Sub Directories\Wiget.exe"`

Note the \ after the Var srcpath because it is included in that var.
Use quotes when calling the Var, not when declaring, and then spaces won't be an issue.

Comment: but this `%~dp0` is a hard-coded value?